# A SoftwareSerial library for SAMD boards

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, adafruit

So I've got three boards that I'm using to test this ([modified](http://www.hackerscapes.com/2014/11/how-to-save-data-from-arduino-to-a-csv-file-using-processing/)) code:

```
int sensor1Pin = A0;
int sensor2Pin = A1;
int sensor3Pin = A2;


float sensors[] = {0,0,0};

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

sensors[0] = analogRead(sensor1Pin);
sensors[1] = analogRead(sensor2Pin);
sensors[2] = analogRead(sensor3Pin);

Serial.print(sensors[0]);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(sensors[1]);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(sensors[1]);
}
```

An Uno, a Feather M0, and an MKR1000. 
The code will only work on the Uno because it's AVR-based whereas the other two boards are SAMD. When running on a feather, you get this error:

```
/home/ghylama/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial_master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:260:2: error: #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors
     #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors
```

However, the resolution of the Uno is too low for my purposes (its DAC has a resolution of 10, whereas I need a resolution of 12, minimum). Are there any libraries/workarounds that I can use for this purpose?

I've tried SoftwareSerial, NeoSWSerial, and [this one](https://github.com/arduino-org/Arduino/commit/1364019868e2ad044c87dd0f143052a92eebda98).

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, what exactly is the question? How to add Serial (/UART) ports to your Feather M0? Or about the DAC? You are using `analogRead` here though, which uses the ADC.

Comment: What has serial to do with DAC (ADC?) resolution?

Comment: Sorry if my wording was unclear but I've been at this for a while now so I've got tunnel vision.
Running this code on a feather gives this error:

Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial_master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:260:2:error: #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors
 #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors

Thing is, I can run this on an Uno without issues but I want it on a feather. The DAC has nothing to do with serial but that is _my constraint_. I need a library that does the same job as SoftwareSerial but for M0.

Comment: Why do you need *software* serial?  An ARM part will typically have multiple *hardware* serial ports.

Comment: @gre_gor Serial has nothing to do with that. My problem is that I am trying to get the SoftwareSerial library to run on devices it was not designed for. I need it to run on a device with a higher DAC resolution (Duo, Zero, Feather).

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am trying to save data from three sensors to an excel sheet. I wanted to do this by using Processing + Arduino IDE with the code from this link: http://www.hackerscapes.com/2014/11/how-to-save-data-from-arduino-to-a-csv-file-using-processing/
Is there a better way?

Comment: That has nothing to do with *software* serial, any serial implementation should work.  Software serial is a *hack* to deal with the fact that the classic Arduino only has 1 port.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It's there in the original Arduino code, line 27. Seemed pretty important so I left it in. So that example would work without it?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the algorithm, and *everything* to do with the limitations of the ATmega328p.  **Which you are not using**.  If you're going to run programs you don't understand, and argue with the people who explain them to you, then you need to stick to doing things *exactly* as described, *without* trying to run them on alternate hardware.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not arguing, I just want to understand what is seemingly obvious to everyone else. Sorry if it came off that way. Now that you explained what software serial is, i get it. So since the only use for that library is as a fix for a limitation, i'm removing that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will restate the problem as I have understood it: You want more Serial objects, aka more UART ports.

On your Adafruit Feather M0 with its SAMD21G18 Cortex-M0+ MCU, you have six SERCOM peripherals which you can arbitrarily configure to be a UART, I2C or SPI port. Each peripheral can have its connections routed to several different pins on the board. It is a very versatile piece of hardware.

Don't use a SoftwareSerial library made for AVR MCUs when you have the hardware. Adafruit's guide shows how you can reconfigure those SERCOMs to get additional `Serial` objects.

https://learn.adafruit.com/using-atsamd21-sercom-to-add-more-spi-i2c-serial-ports?view=all#creating-a-new-serial